# How to loop through preceding siblings up to a point

Tags: xslt

I have this XML:

```
<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br/>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br/>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br/>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br/>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <br/>
</p>
```

I would like to be able to select the `<br/>` tag first and then loop through the spans above them. The reason for this is to get rid of the `<br/>` tags and replace with `<p></p>` tags as below:

```
<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
</p>
```

This is the sort of xslt I came up with:

```
<xsl:template match="br">
    <p>
    <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::span">
         <span>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
         </span>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I know it's wrong as it will pick up all the spans within the P tag not just the ones before the previous br tag. Any suggestions truely appreciated
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to make use of a **key** to match all **span** that precede a given **br** tag

```
<xsl:key name="para" match="span" use="generate-id(following-sibling::br[1])" />
```

i.e Group all **span** tags by the first **br** that immediately follows them.

You can then match on the **br** elements, and use this key to get all the associate **span** tags that precede it

```
<xsl:template match="br">
   <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('para', generate-id())" />
   </p>
```

Here is the complete XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="para" match="span" use="generate-id(following-sibling::br[1])" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="body/p" />
      </body>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="br" />
      <xsl:if test="span[not(following-sibling::br)]">
         <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="span[not(following-sibling::br)]" />
         </p>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="br">
      <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('para', generate-id())" />
      </p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input XML (I have asssumed your sample is enclosed in a **body** tag to make it valid XML

```
<body>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 1</span>
      <br/>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 2</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Foo 3</span>
      <span>Foo 4</span>
      <br/>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 5</span>
      <span>Foo 6</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Foo 7</span>
      <span>Foo 8</span>
      <span>Foo 9</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Foo 10</span>
   </p>
</body>
```

The following is output:

```
<body>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 1</span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 2</span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 3</span>
      <span>Foo 4</span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 5</span>
      <span>Foo 6</span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 7</span>
      <span>Foo 8</span>
      <span>Foo 9</span>
   </p>
   <p>
      <span>Foo 10</span>
   </p>
</body>
```

Do note that as an example, I have added a case to cope with **span** tags that have no following **br** tags within a paragraph.